# MYSQL insert null for not null default column

Tags: mysql

I have curious about why some not null column already set default value, but during insert sql script, it will throw error.

Here is the sample table

```
drop table if exists `delivery`;
create table `delivery`(
    `price` BIGINT not null default 0,
    `created_time` TIMESTAMP(6) not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (6)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4
;
```

Let's say, execute the three statement below, only the second statement will not throw error

```
insert into `delivery` (`price`,`created_time`) values (null, null);
insert into `delivery` (`price`,`created_time`) values (1, null);
insert into `delivery` (`price`,`created_time`) values (null, now());
```

So does it have anyway to insert null for bigint datatype column and make it execute success? And any ideas for the logic behind.

Comment: These kind of behaviours are vastly affected by the SQL_MODE variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't insert null values since you have `NOT NULL` constraints on the columns.

The first and third statement throw an error since you are trying to insert a null value into the column `price` and/or `created_time`, and that clearly doesn't satisfy the constraint(s).

If you really want to allow null values, then remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on the column(s).

Alternatively, you could **sucessfully** run your SQL statements as shown below:

```
insert into `delivery` () values ();
insert into `delivery` (`price`) values (1);
insert into `delivery` (`created_time`) values (now());

select * from `delivery`;
```

Result:

```
price  created_time              
-----  --------------------------
    0  2020-04-16 09:48:23.505147
    1  2020-04-16 09:48:25.549202
    0  2020-04-16 09:48:26.0
```

**EDIT**:

The second query actually succeeds in MySQL 5.7; it silently ignores the **explicit** null value and uses the default value.

It seems that the behavior was fixed in MySQL 8.x since it fails now (as it should).

Comment: Why does the 2nd statement work when it sets `created_time` to `null`, and `created_time` is also `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @kmoser The second one fails with: `Error: Column 'created_time' cannot be null - SQLState:  23000 - ErrorCode: 1048`. See example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jSe88MiqpD2D9haN9sgDDw/0

Comment: @TheImpaler I was able to execute it for the 2nd statement, but it's local setup db

Comment: @TheImpaler Interesting, I tested the 2nd query on MySQL 5.7 and it worked.

Comment: The null-behaviour specifically for timestamps is determined by the [`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp)- and strict-mode-configuration. Check them. Other incredible fun stuff you can try with timestamps and nulls: the behaviour can be different when you insert 1 or 2 rows. For all other datatypes, the behaviour is as The Impaler describes.